# How to filter an already rendered calendar view of a specific date with categories (taxonomy terms)?

Tags: views, datetime

I'm using the latest dev-versions of date/views/calendar/ctools to create an event calendar to display a variety of different events. These events are created with a content-type "event" and classified by a vocabulary (e.g. "movie" or "sport").

I have an already working block of the calendar (showing the current month by default and linking to the corresponding date). If i click on a date i have a list of every event on that date.

How can i reduce the results of that list through the taxonomy terms (movie, sport)?

Any hint or solution is very appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your "list of every event on that date" is generated by Views, you can add a Filter to Views based on Taxonomy Term.  This can then either be exposed to the user so they can pick Movie or Sport - or you can select which one you want explicitly for them.

See selection options below - you'd likely want "Taxonomy: Term" (and you'd be doing this in the Filter - not Contextual Filter).

[image: Taxonomy filter options]

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is a huge improvement to what i want to achieve. I was trying to set up "contextual filters" of all kind. Thanks again for poninting in the right direction...

Comment: No problem - glad it helped!  Views is powerful, but takes a little time to get the hang of.